# What is the and equivalent of where in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

hi i am trying to get a list of employees that have 2 roles. I have a table employees_roles that look like this

```
employeeID RoleID
1          1
1          2
2          1
```

I am trying to get all employees that have both role 1 and 2
i have tried:

```
$employees = Employee::where('companyID', $company->id)
            ->whereHas('employeeRoles', function ($query) use ($roles) {
                $query->whereIn('roleID', $roles);
            })->get()
```

This brings back both employee with id 1 and 2 where i just want it to bring back employee 1.
Is there a whereIn equivalent that use an "And" check and not an "OR" check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$employees = Employee::where('companyID', $company->id);
foreach ($roles as $role) {
   $employees->whereHas('employeeRoles', function ($query) use ($role) {
      $query->where('roleID', $role);
   });
}
        
$employees = $employees->get();
```

Just add 2 `whereHas` condition

Comment: ive tried the multiple where() clauses however thiis doesnt bring back any data

Comment: You have not use multiple where inside one whereHas. It will be always return nothing

Comment: the roles are also not specific they can be any combination of roles specified by the user

Comment: cool i used the multiple wherehas and that worked... thank you